# Run a cypress command if content is present and skip if content is not present

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

Hi I am working with cypress for UI testing. Based on user we do have additional button on the page.

Is there a way cypress can look for a button and run the commands if button is present and skip the command if button is absent thus preventing from element not found error.

```
<div class="btn btn-success" id="editButton">Edit</div>
```

Cypress code is

```
    if (!cy.get('div[id=editButton]')) {
        this.skip();
    } else {
        cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click();
    }
```

And yet cypress throws element not found error.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use a variation of [Dynamic Text](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Dynamic-text) test

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {

  const button = $body.find('div[id=editButton]')
  if (button.length) {
    // yup found it
    cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
  }

  // don't need this.skip()
})
```

Please see the caveats on that page about conditional testing. If your `$body.find('div[id=editButton]')` fails because the button has not appeared yet, you will need to add more assertions to the test.

---

Another approach is to test for different classes of user. This makes your test suite more complete

For example,

```js
it('tests the admin user', () => {
  cy.login('admin')
  cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
  ...  
  callCommonUserTests()
})
```

```js
it('tests the read-only user', () => {
  cy.login('read-only')
  // cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()  // edit button not available
  ...  
  callCommonUserTests()
})
```

Now the test suite is much simpler and less prone to timing issues.

You can consolidate code common for all users in functions or custom commands.

Answer (score 1):

To use jQuery with `Cypress.$` you can test the existence without failing the test

```js
it('tests the edit button', () => {
  if (Cypress.$('#editButton').length) {
    cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
    // rest of test
  }
})
```

Or

```js
it('tests the edit button', () => {

  if (!Cypress.$('#editButton').length) {
    this.skip()                              // exit the test here
  }

  cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
  // rest of test
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the cypress command you have to use a JQuery command for this. And in that you have to check the length. If its 0, then the element doesn't exist.

```js
if (Cypress.$('div[id=editButton]').length == 0) {
  this.skip()
} else {
  cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the below option.

```js
cy.get('div[id="editButton"]')
  .then (($element) => {
    if($element.length) cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `Edit` button is on the page without failing the test

```js
cy.get('div.btn').then($buttons => {
  if ($buttons.text().includes('Edit')) {
    cy.get('div[id=editButton]').click()
  })
})
```